# Get shared link to a file Dropbox API v2.0 c#

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox.Net API v2.0 to upload document to Dropbox:

```
private async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string localPath, string remotePath)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var s = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(remotePath, body: fileStream);
        }
    }
```

How do I get a shared link to the uploaded document?

I have tried that:

```
await dbx.Sharing.GetSharedLinkFileAsync(remotePath);
```

But got the following error:

```
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>shared_link_not_found/.</ExceptionMessage>
```

I'm nissing something but not sure what, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
var result = await  dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(remotePath);
var url = result.Url;
```

That worked perfectly.

Comment: yes but when the file has a shared link already this will throw an exception of type: shared_link_already_exists, I'm trying to get a link that is already shared

Comment: why can't you use the GetSharedLink function?

Answer (score 4):

```
var link = dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(FolderName + "/" + UploadFileName);
if (link.Result.Links.Count == 0)
{
 var result = 
        dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(FolderName+"/"+UploadFileName);
 string url = result.Result.Url;
}
 else
{
 string url = link.Result.Links[0].Url;
 URL = url;
}
```

This way you can check existing links and add new if required.